# IntelliJ won't show test overview when adding Gradle project property

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have two IntelliJ Gradle run targets: One that simply executes the `test` task, and one that executes `test -PmyProperty=true`.

When I run the first target, IntelliJ properly runs the tests and shows the results in the familar tree. But when I run the second one, the tests are executed, a JUnit report is generated, but IntelliJ doesn't show the test overview.

If it matters, this is what Gradle does with the property:

```
test {
  useJUnit {
    if (project.properties["myProperty"] != "true") {
      excludeCategories("MyCategory")
    }
  }
}
```

How do I get IntelliJ to show the test results as normal?

Comment: IntelliJ Community 2021.2.2, Gradle 6.9.1, JUnit 4.13.2